# GET 405 405 (Method Not Allowed) error

Tags: angularjs, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am using angularjs with jersey backend.I am sending a http request from angular using $http post method and i am trying to parse it in the backend using POJO class.Basically my controller sends key to the backend using post method and the backend will return list of data regarding that key from the database.But when i try to do this i get the error
" GET http://localhost:8081/hibernate-jersey-angularjs/rest/leave/list 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

Following is my cod

```js
@POST
 @Path("/list")
 @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
 @Produces({ "application/json" })
 public List<LeaveQueue> list(numPojo s) {
  List<LeaveQueue> l=  new ShowLeaveDao().getAllLeaves();
  Iterator i=l.iterator();
  while(i.hasNext())
  {
   LeaveQueue m=(LeaveQueue)i.next();
   System.out.println(m.getNum());
  }
  
  return l;
 }
```

and my controller

```js
app.controller("MyDbController", function($scope, $http,mynum,myname) {
    //$scope.data = [{title: 'welcome hello'},{title: 'great testing'}];
 $scope.test={};
 test.num=mynum;
 var jsonData=JSON.stringify(test);
 console.log("InsideListController"+jsonData);
 
    $http({
     url:"rest/leave/list",
     method:"POST",
     data: jsonData,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} 
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("error from leave list controller");
    })
});
```

and my web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container, see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>trial.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.abc.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Please help .

Comment: sounds like a bad URL, check if your url is correct

Answer (score 0):

In your code , your resource use @Post annotation which means you can only invoke this resource by Post method.

Comment: Your error is "GET http://localhost:8081/hibernate-jersey-angularjs/rest/leave/list 405 (Method Not Allowed)" . I think that's a GET method.